# Не добавляется кнопка в список в админ панели Django

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно добавить кнопку в разделе админки, где все новости

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% block object-tools %}
  <form action="import/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="Импорт" />
  </form>
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

Не работает, кнопки нет, а если пройти дальше в саму новость, то ошибка

```
Error during template rendering
In template C:\PantusDjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\admin\base.html, error at line 15

Reverse for 'app_list' with keyword arguments '{'app_label': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['admin/(?P<app_label>auth|backApi)/$']
```

Если меняю в первой строчке

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
на 
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
```

то, всё работает, кнопка появляется, но не там где я хочу, а в редакторе самой статьи.
Почему не работает change_list.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Дело было в названии самого файла исправил имя файла на change_list.html всё работает.